# .htaccess changes REQUEST_METHOD to GET - if the URL does not have params or a trailing slash

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm building an api eg. `https://example.com/my-api/api.php`

Then I use the following .htaccess file to make the api usable via `https://example.com/my-api`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.php/$1/ [L,QSA]
```

The file works, however when my api-call doesn't end with a trailing slash or has some parameters set, the $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] becomes GET.

Examples:

```
POST https://example.com/my-api/foo #becomes GET
POST https://example.com/my-api/foo/ #stays POST
POST https://example.com/my-api/foo?bar=1 #stays POST

POST https://example.com/my-api/foo/bar #becomes GET
POST https://example.com/my-api/foo/bar/ #stays POST
POST https://example.com/my-api/foo/bar?abc=1 #stays POST
```

How could I change this behavior (and is this desirable) or should I inform the users of this api to always end their calls with a trailing slash?
When the trailing slash is added, the api works as expected.

I tested this behaviour mostly via PostMan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because of a missing slash in your URI which points to a real directory. Apache's `mod_dir` module adds a trailing slash for those requests and performs a `301` redirect that results in another `GET` request.

You can disable this behavior but also important to disable option to list directory content for security reasons.

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)$ api.php/$1/ [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works like this - though I will have to check with our ICT department, on how our Azure servers are configured. This .htaccess works perfect on localhost, but not on our Azure Webservice. So I marked it as correct (as it is, just not in my specific situation)

Comment: I want to redirect all requests (GET, PUT, POST) from the old domain to the new domain. I have tried the above solution but it does not work. Redirect will convert POST request into GET so not working. Please, anyone, suggest a solution according to my requirement

Comment: This rule has no external redirect hence it will with for all GET, PUT, POST verbs.